# Minimal sufficient statistic: a measurability issue in a well-known theorem

Tags: sufficient-statistics, measure-theory

Given a statistical model $\{\mathbb{P}_\theta\,|\,\theta\in\Theta\}$ on $(\Omega,\mathscr{F})$, and given a real-valued random variable $X$, we say a real-valued random variable $T=T(X)$ is a sufficient statistic if $X_*\mathbb{P}_\theta(dx|T)$ (the conditional distribution of $X$ given $T$) is independent of $\theta$. We also say a sufficient statistic $S$ is minimal if for all other sufficient statistics $T$ there is a measurable $\phi:(\mathbb{R},Bor(\mathbb{R}))\to(\mathbb{R},Bor(\mathbb{R}))$ such that $S=\phi(T)$ $\mathbb{P}_\theta$-a.e. for any $\theta$.

Suppose that all $X_*\mathbb{P}_\theta(dx)$ are absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebsegue measure with density $f(x|\theta)$, and that $X,S$ are real-valued random variables. A well-known theorem says that if "for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ $\frac{f(x|\theta)}{f(y|\theta)}$ is independent of $\theta$ if and only if $S(x)=S(y)$" then $S$ is a minimal sufficient statistic.

A proof of this theorem can be found [here (Thm 3.4)](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/Dept/People/djsteaching/S1B-15-03-sufficiency-4.pdf.). This proof (which is the same as all other proofs that I saw) however only shows that, given another sufficient statistic $T$, there exists a function $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $S=\phi(T)$ $\mathbb{P}_\theta$-a.e. for any $\theta$, but doesn't show it is measurable.

My question is simple: how does one show  $\phi$ is measurable?

***UPDATE*** :
The answer to my question seems to be that $\phi$ need not be measurable in the general case and that the theorem as I stated it is wrong. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448413/minimal-sufficient-statistic-a-measurability-issue-in-a-well-known-theorem/448694#448694) for more details.

Comment: The theorem based on the ratio of densities implies that the property is true almost everywhere since these densities are uniquely defined a.e.. This means that $S$ is also defined a.e.

Comment: Thank you, I have now changed the equalities to a.e. equalities.

Comment: My point was that the a.e. definition could prove enough to bypass measurability issues.

Comment: Can you be more explicit please? How do you modify a non-measurable $\phi$ to get a measurable $\tilde{\phi}$ with the same property that $S=\tilde{\phi}(T)$ $\mathbb{P}_\theta$-a.e. for all $\theta$?

Comment: Also asked & answered at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448413/minimal-sufficient-statistic-a-measurability-issue-in-a-well-known-theorem

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen That answer on mathoverflow does not address the point of my question.

Comment: @Titti, check Shao where he used the existence of minimal sufficient statistic when the family is dominated by a sigma-finite measure and the usual argument to show that the function is one-one. He then resorts to a result in Parthasarathy which basically says the inverse function is measurable.

Comment: @User1865345-solidarityMods thank you! The way Shao does it is very interesting and works perfectly fine. However, the fact that he is able to prove the result only for $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued $X$ and has to appeal to that deep result in Parthasarathy (whose prove requires descriptive set theory) suggests that this is in fact the best that can be done and that for a general $X$ the function $\phi$ need not be measurable. Do you know if this is indeed the case?

Comment: The fact that the theorem might not hold in full generality and that some technical conditions need to be imposed is also suggested by the fact that Lehmann and Scheffé in their paper do impose some restrictions even to get existence of a possibly non-measurable $\mathbb{\phi}$ (Theorem 6.1 and 6.3 in http://www.jstor.org/stable/25048038).

Comment: I remember I came across a more general result. But I cannot remember the book. I will update you once I go to my department library next week @Titti.

Comment: On second thought, I now believe that also what Shao does is not correct. In his notations, the equality $\phi(g(S(x)))=S(x)$  holds true for all $x$ outside a null measurable set $A$. Hence $\phi=g^{-1}$ on $g(S(\mathcal{X})\setminus S( A)))$, which however may not be Borel (since $S(\mathcal{X})$ and $S(A)$ may not be) and hence the result in Parthasarathy is not applicable.